# how to debug the error of "Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault"

Tags: linux, fortran, gfortran, netcdf

I am running a Fortran exe, and I get the error:

```
 set_nml_output Echo NML values to log file only
 Trying to open namelist log dart_log.nml
 PE 0: initialize_mpi_utilities:  Running with            8  MPI processes.

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
```

Then I try to use gdb to find someting, it reports

```
[New LWP 9883]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.
Core was generated by `./filter'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00002af8e021390c in netcdf::nf90_open (
    path=<error reading variable: value requires 57959040 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, mode=0, 
    ncid=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439346b0>, 
    chunksize=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>, 
    cache_size=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe43934530>, 
    cache_nelems=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe43934528>, 
    cache_preemption=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345a0>, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    comm=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345a8>, 
    info=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345b0>, 
    _path=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345b8>) at netcdf4_file.f90:39
39  netcdf4_file.f90: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002af8e021390c in netcdf::nf90_open (
    path=<error reading variable: value requires 57959040 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>, mode=0, 
    ncid=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439346b0>, 
    chunksize=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>, 
    cache_size=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe43934530>, 
    cache_nelems=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe43934528>, 
    cache_preemption=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345a0>, 
    comm=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345a8>, 
    info=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345b0>, 
    _path=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe439345b8>) at netcdf4_file.f90:39
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe43934598
```

and the netcdf4_file.f90:39 is shown as follows:

```
if (present(cache_size) .or. present(cache_nelems) .or. &
       present(cache_preemption)) then
     ret = nf_get_chunk_cache(size_in, nelems_in, preemption_in)
     if (ret .ne. nf90_noerr) then
        nf90_open = ret
        return
     end if
     if (present(cache_size)) then
        size_out = cache_size     #### line 39
     else
        size_out = size_in
     end if
     if (present(cache_nelems)) then
        nelems_out = cache_nelems
     else
        nelems_out = nelems_in
     end if
```

Does the version of netcdf is related with the problem, or some setting should be modified?

Can anyone give me some suggestion of how to fix this problem,
since I am not quiet familiar with these.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please enable all debugging options your compiler has. Like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`. The best would be to compile the libraries in the same way for the debugging test, but it is normally too awkward. Usually we need much more code, see [mcve].

Comment: Your critical error, at least in GDB, seems to be here: `path=<error reading variable: value requires 57959040 bytes, which is more than max-value-size>`. The rest of the traceback seems to be a consequence of this. See [this link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-Sizes.html) for more information. Edit: also, make sure that your version of NetCDF had the option for parallel I/O configured during compilation. That could possibly be another avenue where this error could occur.

Comment: It looks like calls to the netcdf library. You compare `ret` to `nf90_noerr` -- which suggests that you are using the Fortran90 library. But at the same time you assign a value to `nf90_open`, either because it's a variable or it is the name of the function -- and I'm fairly certain that `nf90_open` is a function in that library. Is it possible that you have a naming conflict?

Comment: @chw21, I imagine that the source quoted there is _from_ the NetCDF library.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston, after I set max-value-size unlimited,  the error of that line would disappear, but others are not.I need to learn more how to debug,Thanks, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @francescalus, yes, the last quote is from netcdf library

Comment: @chw21, the exe I run is called filter, but it failed, and I tried to use gdb to debug.It reported these error, and said `at netcdf4_file.f90:39`, so I posted last quote.

Comment: Follow-up: I’m assuming you’re running this like: `mpiexec -np N ./filter ARGS`, yes? If so, try running this on a single core (with `N=1` or without the `mpiexec` prefix at all). See if the behavior is different. I suspect it might be.

Answer (score 5):

A segmentation fault is really hard to debug, but here are a few things I do:

Compile with debug symbols and run time checks. The flags are compiler dependent, but here are the ones for gfortran and Intel Fortran:

```
gfortran     ifort         effect
------------------------------------------------------
-g           -g            Stores the code inside the binary
-O0          -O0           Disables optimisation
-fbacktrace  -traceback    More informative stack trace
-Wall        -warn all     Enable all compile time warnings
-fcheck=all  -check all    Enable run time checks
```

With a little bit of luck, when your program crashes after being compiled this way, it will be easier to deduce what's going wrong.